# linear algebra about matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*I* is an identity matrix with appropriate dimension. How to prove for
any given matrix A ∈ R^m×n and any positive number µ :

Both $A^TA + \mu I$ and $AA^T + \mu I$ are invertible.

One way to prove matrix is invertible is to prove the det of matrix is not equal to zero, but i have no idea about it, really need some help.

Comment: Use correct formatting. Put a "$" at the beginning and at the end of every math notation. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negation of the statement is that $A^TA+\mu I$ is NOT invertible for $\mu>0$.

That means $A^TA (v)=-\mu I(v)$ for some non-zero vector $v$.  So your problem   boils down to showing that $A^TA$ cannot have real negative eigenvalue.

Now note that $A^TA $ (and $AA^T$) is a symmetric matrix. For a given vector $v$ calculate the norm of $A^TAv$. This norm is is $v^TA^TA A^TAv\geq0$. Can you complete the proof now, choosing $v$ as an eigenvector?

Comment: I did not say norm of a matrix. Read it again: I said norm of $A^TAv$ which is a *vector*. To get its norm, the inner product (with itself) is obtained as $v^tA^TAA^tv$.